# type object 'Skills' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am getting this error "type object 'Skills' has no attribute '_default_manager'"

I am getting the following error "type object 'Skills' has no attribute 'objects'" while trying to run my Django project

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from portfolio_app.models import GuestUser,InquiryForm,Skills,Facts,Education,Service,UserTestimonials
from .forms import GuestUser,InquiryForm,Skills,Facts,Education,Service,UserTestimonials
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                          DetailView,CreateView,
                                          UpdateView,DeleteView)
from django.views import generic
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin



class TestView(generic.ListView):
     model = Skills
     template_name = 'portfolio_app/test.html'
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse

class Skills(models.Model):
    skill_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    skill_value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill_name
```

`test.html`

```
{% extends 'portfolio_app/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


{% for skill in skills_list %}  
{{skill.skill_name}}}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from portfolio_app.models import *
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.fact,name='index'),
    #path('index/',views.SkillView.as_view,name='index'),
    path('about/',views.about_me,name='about'),
            
    path('service/',views.ServiceView.as_view(),name='service'),
            path('resume/',views.ResumeView.as_view(),name='resume'),
            
    path('contact/',views.ContactView.as_view(),name='contact'),
    path('test/',views.TestView.as_view(),name='test'),
]
```

Please help
I am getting the following error "type object 'Skills' has no attribute 'objects'" while trying to run my Django project

Comment: Could you show the code, where you import your model `Skills` in the `TestView`?

Comment: I have attached screenshot of my views.py, template, forms.py, models.py and urls.py

Comment: @GiovanniTshibangu paste your code, images are not the best way to share code.

Comment: I just updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ambiguous imports:

```
from portfolio_app.models Skills
from .forms Skills
```

You can change your model import like this:

```
from portfolio_app.models Skills as SkillsModel
```

and then use `SkillsModel` instead of `Skills`:

```
class TestView(generic.ListView):
       model = SkillsModel
       template_name = 'portfolio_app/test.html'
```

Or you can get rid of unnecessary `.forms` imports.

Comment: I did import that ###from portfolio_app.models import GuestUser,InquiryForm,Skills,Facts,Education,Service,UserTestimonials

Comment: type object 'Skills' has no attribute '_default_manager'

Comment: I can not see it in `views.py`. Unfortunately, I can not help you if you don't specify the full code of `views.py`.

Comment: It looks like you have a view with a similar name or something like that.

Comment: I am going to post the full code on this post

Comment: I am sorry if it looks messy

Comment: Updated my answer.